# Job clusters in Databricks linked service Azure Data Factory are only uploading one init script

Tags: azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

Job clusters in Databricks linked service Azure Data Factory are only uploading one init script even though I have two in my configuration. I believe this a recent bug in ADF as my setup was uploading the two scripts one week ago but it is not anymore. Also I tested Databricks clusters API and I can upload two scripts.

[Databricks Init Scripts Set up in Azure Data Factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFFAv.png)